# Querying data with additional column that creates a number for ordering purposes

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a "queue" system by adding an arbitrary column that creates a number based on a condition and date, to sort the importance of a row.

For example, below is the query result I pulled in Postgres:

```
Table: task
Result:
description | status/condition| task_created       |
bla         | A               | 2019-12-01 07:00:00|
pikachu     | A               | 2019-12-01 16:32:10|
abcdef      | B               | 2019-12-02 18:34:22|
doremi      | B               | 2019-12-02 15:09:43|
lalala      | A               | 2019-12-03 22:10:59|
```

In the above, each task has a date/timestamp and status/condition applied to them. I would like to create another column that gives a number to a row where it prioritises the older tasks first, BUT if the condition is B, then we take the older task of those in B as first priority.

The expected end result (based on the example) should be:

```
Table1: task
description | status/condition| task_created       | priority index 
bla         | A               | 2019-12-01 07:00:00| 3
pikachu     | A               | 2019-12-01 16:32:10| 4
abcdef      | B               | 2019-12-02 18:34:22| 2
doremi      | B               | 2019-12-02 15:09:43| 1
lalala      | A               | 2019-12-03 22:10:59| 5
```

For priority number, 1 being most urgent to do/resolve, while 5 being the least.

How would I go about adding this additional column into the existing query? especially since there's another condition apart from just the task_created date/time.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Now what exactly is your question?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe apologies, I just edited the question. In the original query, I don't have the column called 'priority index' (or whatever I decide to name it later). This information is not in the table as well.

The question is, how would I go about adding a column which creates an index based on the conditions I provided?

Comment: Oh, now I understand. You are not talking about indexes at all, but you want to add a column that defines a certain ordering on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe want the Rank or Dense Rank function (depends on your needs) [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html).

If you don't need a conditional order on the status you can use this one.

```
SELECT *,
       rank() OVER (
           ORDER BY status desc, task_created
           ) as priority_index
FROM task
```

If you need a custom order based on the value of the status:

```
SELECT *,
       rank() OVER (
           ORDER BY
           CASE status
              WHEN 'B' THEN 1
              WHEN 'A' THEN 2
              WHEN 'C' THEN 3
              ELSE 4
            END, task_created
           ) as priority_index
FROM task
```

If you have few values this is good enough, because we can simply specify your custom order. But if you have a lot of values and the ordering information is fixed, then it should have its own table.

Comment: Thanks for this! But what if I have more than 2 statuses? I have about 4 status in reality, but 'B' specifically will get priority over all other.

Comment: Can you provide a better example? Are the status in a specific order?

Comment: I edited the answer, check if it is what you are looking for

Comment: hey sorry I just got back on. I just tried the custom order you posted, many thanks!
To answer your previous questions, the statuses aren't in any specific order. It's just whatever people tag the task to be, and the data gets filled into the database. That's why I'm trying to create the additional column so I can sort the priority by status + date/time.

Thank you again for this!